# ¿Como Envío correo electrónico al administrador de la tienda en commerce 2 drupal 9?

Tags: php, drupal9

Tengo un problema en Drupal 9 Commerce 2 a la hora de enviar el correo de compra que ha hecho el cliente al vendedor de ese producto.

He logrado utilizar el my-theme-order-receipt.thml.twig pero esto hace que el correo llegue solamente al usuario que ha comprado el producto y necesito que esos datos también le lleguen al vendedor de ese producto.

tengo configurado mail system  y swift mailer de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la theme tengo en templates:

my_theme-order-receipt.thml.twig

y en el my_template.theme :

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function my_template_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [
    'commerce_order_receipt' => [
      'template' => 'my_template-order-receipt',
      'base hook' => 'commerce_order_receipt',
    ],
  ];
}
```

También estoy utilizando EventSubcriber con el archivo OrderFulfillmentSubscriber.php pero hasta ahora no he resuelto nada con este archivo.
my_module/EventSubscriber/OrderFulfillmentSubscriber.php

```
  <?php

    namespace Drupal\tracking_number_email\EventSubscriber;

    use Drupal\state_machine\Event\WorkflowTransitionEvent;
    use Drupal\Core\Language\LanguageManagerInterface;
    use Drupal\Core\Mail\MailManagerInterface;
    use Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\StringTranslationTrait;
    use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

    /**
     * Sends an email when the order transitions to Fulfillment.
     */
    class OrderFulfillmentSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

      use StringTranslationTrait;

      /**
       * The language manager.
       *
       * @var \Drupal\Core\Language\LanguageManagerInterface
       */
      protected $languageManager;

      /**
       * The mail manager.
       *
       * @var \Drupal\Core\Mail\MailManagerInterface
       */
      protected $mailManager;

      /**
       * Constructs a new OrderFulfillmentSubscriber object.
       *
       * @param \Drupal\Core\Language\LanguageManagerInterface $language_manager
       *   The language manager.
       * @param \Drupal\Core\Mail\MailManagerInterface $mail_manager
       *   The mail manager.
       */
      public function __construct(
        LanguageManagerInterface $language_manager,
        MailManagerInterface $mail_manager
      ) {
        $this->languageManager = $language_manager;
        $this->mailManager = $mail_manager;
      }

      /**
       * {@inheritdoc}
       */
      public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
        $events = [
          'commerce_order.fulfill.post_transition' => ['sendEmail', -100],
        ];
        return $events;
      }

      /**
       * Sends the email.
       *
       * @param \Drupal\state_machine\Event\WorkflowTransitionEvent $event-       
       *   The transition event.
       */
      public function sendEmail(WorkflowTransitionEvent $event) {
        // Create the email.
        $order = $event->getEntity();
        $to = $order->getEmail();
        $params = [
          'from' => $order->getStore()->getEmail(),
          'subject' => $this->t(
            'Regarding your order [#@number]',
            ['@number' => $order->getOrderNumber()]
          ),
          'body' => ['#markup' => $this->t(
            'Your order with #@number that you have placed with us has been processed and is awaiting fulfillment.',
            ['@number' => $order->getOrderNumber()]
          )],
        ];

        // Set the language that will be used in translations.
        if ($customer = $order->getCustomer()) {
          $langcode = $customer->getPreferredLangcode();
        }
        else {
          $langcode = $this->languageManager->getDefaultLanguage()->getId();
        }

        // Send the email.
        $this->mailManager->mail('commerce', 'receipt', $to, $langcode, $params);
      }

    }
```

No se que otra configuración me falta para que ese mismo correo(plantilla con esos mismos datos) le llegue con copia oculta al administrador de la tienda para informarle que tiene un pedido y los datos correspondientes a ese pedido. Alguna idea, por favor, lo agradezco con antelación.

Answer (score -1):

Esto al final lo resolvi en el metodo senEmail de la sgt manera:

```
$params = [
          'from' => 'admin@admin.com',
          'subject' => $this->t(
            'Regarding your order [#@number]',
            ['@number' => $order->getOrderNumber()]
          ),
          'body' => ['#markup' => $this->t(
            'Your order with #@number that you have placed with us has been processed and is awaiting fulfillment.',
            ['@number' => $order->getOrderNumber()]
          )],
        ];

        // Set the language that will be used in translations.
        if ($customer = $order->getCustomer()) {
          $langcode = $customer->getPreferredLangcode();
        }
        else {
          $langcode = $this->languageManager->getDefaultLanguage()->getId();
        }

        // Send the email.
        $this->mailManager->mail('commerce', 'receipt', $order->getStore()->getEmail(), $langcode, $params);
```

En el from en tanto he puesto a mano el email del administrador del sitio, eso sería lo que tengo que investigar ahora como sacar esa email y el $order->getStore()->getEmail(), sería el email de la tienda, porque el email del comprador ya se lo envía por defecto. Una cosa que si me gustaría darle forma al email que le llega a vendedor que no se ve bonito y que tenga un formato html , pero no se como hacerlo, si me podéis dar alguna idea, lo agradezco.

He probado a añadirle el formato dentro del #markup pero no le hace caso.